# VBA UserForm Space Between Labels Algorithm

Tags: vba, excel

I have an algorithm in code of userform that I'm using to add names of months to a VBA userform dynamically. I want to add the months 3 times as an header for 3 different categories. My problem is that in the Algorithm I created the space between the two first months is one  and between the second month and the third the space is double. the months values is in worksheet 8 in the cells A4 to A7.

it looks like this in the uFebruary
december ___January ______February

Here is my code:

```
'months in commission, workdays and workhours
Dim m As Integer 'm = month
Dim T As Integer 'T=TOP
Dim L As Integer 'L= loop

T = 50
For m = 1 To 3
    For L = 1 To 9
        DATA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(8).Range("A" & m + 3).Value
        Set dLbl = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "dLbl", True)
        With dLbl
            .Top = 70
            If L < 4 Then
                .Left = 700 - (T * m)
            ElseIf L > 6 Then
                .Left = 190 - (T * m)
            Else
                .Left = 450 - (T * m)
            End If

            .Height = 50
            .Caption = DATA
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 11
            .Width = 45
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
        End With
    Next L
Next m
```

Comment: could you add a screen shot with these lables?

Comment: @PawelCzyz unfortunately I cant, I am at work and the system here not allowing me to screen shot and upload. Maybe I could explain better if you will be specific.

Comment: Actually it's unclear what your issue is. What's wrong with your code? Any Errors? What does it do instead of what did you expect? Also you didn't ask a question yet.

Comment: How *wide* is the user form? I find things look odd if it's not very wide, but when it's wide enough the distribution appears OK. What I do find odd, however, is that you're superimposing three labels deep - I only see the last pass through (3, 6, and 9; I appended the value of L to the label name and use that as the caption in my tests).